# Loop through collection - target every item above a certain number

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm looping through my collection to display all my data. Pretty standard stuff - nothing special.

I wan't to target and apply functionality to every element from number 9 onwards.

For example. The first 8 sessions are free, after that I want to append a button to the 9th+ ones to pay.

```
@foreach($sessions as $session)
   <input type="text" name="event" value="{{ $counsellingSession->event_start_time }}" class="form-control datetimepicker" >
@endforeach
```

could i apply a class to all items in position 9 and above.

Comment: It is awesome thinking about how Laravel/Blade makes us all lazy :p). Something like this is what we could have traditionally used a generic Php $counter variable to achieve. Now Blade is cutting all our verbosity :). Anyway, @Martin's answer is cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the magic `$loop` variable Blade templates have in `@foreach` loops like this:

```html
@foreach($sessions as $session)
    @if($loop->index > 8)
        <!-- Display payment button -->
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#loops

Comment: @Andre, also keep in mind that you may need to order your collection (such as by a date) before you render your blade because this is based on the index.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
 $count=0;
@foreach($sessions as $session)
  $count++;
   @if($count >=9)
     here apply your classs
   @else
     <input type="text" name="event" value="{{ $counsellingSession->event_start_time }}" class="form-control datetimepicker" >
   @endif
  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for that is you can use the keys of array in loop,

```
@foreach($sessions as $key => $session)
    @if($key > 8)
        <input type="submit">
    @endif
    <input type="text" name="event" value="{{ $counsellingSession->event_start_time }}"
           class="form-control datetimepicker" >
@endforeach
```